# How to Remove certain rows after extraction in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, grepl

I'm trying to remove certain rows after extraction in R.
original dataset is defined as raw_data.
certain rows are defined as inner_data.

After define inner_data, I want to remove the inner_data in raw_data.

```
inner_data <- raw_data[(grepl("^30", raw_data$start) | grepl("^36", raw_data$start))
                       & (grepl("^30", raw_data$end) | grepl("^36", raw_data$end)), ]
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: This will be very difficult to inform/help in its current state, please provide a small sample of the data. Interesting to me is that you say you want to remove columns but you are grepping rows and removing rows ...

Comment: Hi. You can achieve this by redefining the dataset as a part of the original dataset. Try `raw_data <- raw_data[,1:5]` And in stead of 1:5 you write the columns you want to keep.

Comment: oh my, i edited the question. I mean, I want to remove certain rows.

Is there a way to compare two data frames to eliminate duplicated rows?

Answer (score 2):

Here are two approaches to consider:

**1) use a filter variable**

Instead of constructing `inner_data` directly from `raw_data` in a single step, first create a new column that indicates which output dataset the row belongs to. Use this column to filter out both datasets.

Something like the following:

```r
raw_data = raw_data %>%
  mutate(splitting_col = (grepl("^30", start) | grepl("^36", start))
                       & (grepl("^30", end) | grepl("^36", end)))
inner_data = raw_data %>%
  filter(splitting_col == TRUE)
raw_data = raw_data %>%
  filter(splitting_col == FALSE)
```

**2) use an anti_join**

An anti-join is the operation for removing records from one table after comparison to a second table. Searching "dplyr anti_join" should get you several tutorials on this.

It works similar to a join, but excludes records instead of combining them. Something like the following:

```r
inner_data <- raw_data[(grepl("^30", raw_data$start) | grepl("^36", raw_data$start))
                       & (grepl("^30", raw_data$end) | grepl("^36", raw_data$end)), ]

raw_data = raw_ata %>%
  anti_join(inner_data)
```